# How can i remove this sidebar from my html page?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

[image]

The image given below is screenshot of my JQuery-Mobile project. I got a sidebar which i want to remove.I have a div containing Scrolling table.

Comment: Is this tested on a phone or desktop??. Because if it is on desktop these scrollbars appear. If you haven't tried it with a phone then try it and let us know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one

```
<style type="text/css">
  html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/5GCsJ/570/)

Comment: @rimon.ekjon if this solves your problem, please consider to mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS attribute called `::-webkit-scrollbar`.
You can find many other things to play with this attribute.
Here is a link to W3 School hope it can help you
['How TO - Custom Scrollbar'](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

Comment: You should show how to use that piece of CSS, otherwise, this answer isn't that helpful. It's also bad practice to simply link to another site in a Stack Overflow answer without at least copying and quoting the relevant pieces from the link